# Rstudio breakpoint not hit in modules

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, breakpoints

I have an rshiny app with modules. I use Rstudio to run the app. The breakpoints that I set in modules don't get hit. I use `browser()` to get around this - which works consistently. But the breakpoints are not hit inside modules. The breakpoints in the main app file (where `shinyApp()` is run) are  hit without a problem.

Any suggestions please?